# R data table - join two tables on equation

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to join two tables using an equation with the data.table library?

In SQL this would be something like:

```
r = data.table(ymd=c(20151101, 20151102, 20151103), val=c(1,2,3))

require(sqldf)
sqldf('select t1.*, t2.val as val_prev_day
     from r t1
    join r t2
    on t1.ymd=(t2.ymd+1)
 ')
       ymd val val_prev_day
1 20151102   2            1
2 20151103   3            2
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are actually doing is creating a lagged variable. To achieve that it is not necessary to do a join. Within *data.table*, you can create a lagged variable with the `shift`-function as follows:

```
r[, val_prev_day := shift(val)]
```

which will give you:

```
> r
        ymd val val_prev_day
1: 20151101   1           NA
2: 20151102   2            1
3: 20151103   3            2
```

You can remove the row where `val_prev_day` has an `NA`-value by adding `[!is.na(val_prev_day)]` like this:

```
r[, val_prev_day := shift(val)][!is.na(val_prev_day)]
```

which gives:

```
        ymd val val_prev_day
1: 20151102   2            1
2: 20151103   3            2
```

Answer (score 0):

We remove the first row from 'r' (`tail(r, -1)`) and join `on` 'r' that has the last row removed after adding 1 to the 'ymd'.

```
tail(r,-1)[head(r,-1)[, ymd:=ymd+1],val_prev_day:= i.val ,on = 'ymd'][]
#        ymd val val_prev_day
#1: 20151102   2            1
#2: 20151103   3            2
```

The above is similar to the SQL syntax in the OP's code.

---

Or we can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
setDF(r) %>%
        mutate(val_prev_day= lag(val)) %>%
        na.omit() 
#       ymd val val_prev_day
#2 20151102   2            1
#3 20151103   3            2
```